# Error While Connecting Mobile to ad hoc WiFi network

Tags: wifi

I am able to create an ad hoc WiFi network on my laptop and it is waiting for users. 
Now when I try to connect from my windows phone 7.5 I can find this WiFi, but when I supply the password it says "INCORRECT PASSWORD" and this happens repeatedly even though I am entering the correct password.

Comment: I think Windows Phone does not support ad hoc connection.

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful if you supply more details, but I will assume that you are using internet connection sharing on your Windows 7 laptop.

I had a similar problem with my iPad and it was due to the security protocol Windows was using for the ad hoc network (for me it was WPA2-Personal). Try [changing the encryption](http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/How-to-share-wired-internet-wirelessly-with-a-Windows-7-laptop.aspx) to WEP and see if this works.

WEP is **not very secure** and can easily be cracked, so I would advise using caution.